# Count consecutive values once in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which I have courier delivery data. I have a delivery scheduled every day. I want to count the number of failed deliveries. If a delivery is failed on consecutive days then it should be counted as 1. For example, delivery is scheduled in each day of April 2021. Delivery failed on the day of 15th April. After that delivery failed again from 18th April till 20th April. Although the number of days the delivery failed is 4 days but I want to count the number of failures as 2 because continuous days of failure will be counted as 1.

```
DeliveryId     DeliveryDate     Status
1              2021-04-14       Success
2              2021-04-15       Failure
3              2021-04-16       Success
4              2021-04-17       Success
5              2021-04-18       Failure
6              2021-04-19       Failure
7              2021-04-20       Failure
8              2021-04-21       Success
```

I want a new column that will show the deliveryId of the first failure as below.

```
DeliveryId     DeliveryDate     Status     FailedDeliveryId
1              2021-04-14       Success     
2              2021-04-15       Failure     2
3              2021-04-16       Success     
4              2021-04-17       Success     
5              2021-04-18       Failure     5
6              2021-04-19       Failure     5
7              2021-04-20       Failure     5
8              2021-04-21       Success
```

I have tried a few options but failed to achieve the above result. I used LAG function in my query to find previous delivery status. But the problem is if the delivery is failing for more than 3 or 4 days then I will have to use LAG function to 3 or 4 days back and check the status. I want to make it a dynamic query. Below is what I have used

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN Status='Failure' AND Prev_Status='Success' THEN DeliveryId 
            WHEN Status='Failure' AND Prev_Status='Failure' THEN Prev_DeliveryId 
            END AS FailureInstance 
FROM (
         SELECT *, 
                LAG(Status,1) OVER(ORDER BY DeliveryDate ASC) Prev_Status,
                LAG(DeliveryId,1) OVER(ORDER BY DeliveryDate ASC) Prev_DeliveryId
         FROM   table1 
     ) A
```

Comment: Can you please show your attempt ?

Comment: I have mentioned what I have attempted so far. Please your guidance is needed

Comment: Try `DENSE_RANK` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…

```
declare @t table(DeliveryId int, DeliveryDate date, Status varchar(10));

insert into @t(DeliveryId, DeliveryDate, Status)
values
(10, '2021-04-14', 'Success'),
(20, '2021-04-15', 'Failure'),
(30, '2021-04-16', 'Success'),
(40, '2021-04-17', 'Success'),
(70, '2021-04-18', 'Failure'),
(60, '2021-04-19', 'Failure'),
(50, '2021-04-20', 'Failure'),
(80, '2021-04-21', 'Success');


select *, 
case when Status='Failure' then min(grpDeliveryId) over(partition by grp) end as FailedDeliveryId,
case when Status='Failure' then datediff(minute, min(DeliveryDate) over(partition by grp), min(grpSuccessDate) over(partition by grp) ) end as MinutesDiffFailSuccess
from
(
select *, 
sum(addorcountme) over(order by DeliveryDate) as grp
from
(
select *, 
case when Status='Failure' and lag(Status) over(order by DeliveryDate)='Failure' then null else 1 end as addorcountme,
case when Status='Failure' and lag(Status) over(order by DeliveryDate)='Failure' then null else DeliveryId end as grpDeliveryId,
case when Status='Failure' and lead(Status) over(order by DeliveryDate)='Success' then lead(DeliveryDate) over(order by DeliveryDate) end as grpSuccessDate
from @t
) as t
) as g;



/*
select *, case when Status='Failure' then min(DeliveryId) over(partition by grp) end as FailedDeliveryId
from
(
select *, 
sum(sumorcountme) over(order by DeliveryDate) as grp
from
(
select *, case when Status='failure' and lag(Status) over(order by DeliveryDate)='Failure' then null else 1 end as sumorcountme
from @t
) as t
) as g; */
```

Comment: This looks to me to be working as expected.

Comment: This one works as expected. I also need to calculate the time between First Failure Date and subsequent First Success Date. This will tell me the total time the delivery was failed. Can you modify your query to calculate that as well?

Comment: …@marcin2x4 .. it will not work correctly if the DeliveryIds are not collocated with dates…try switching the ids..eg assign id 70 to 18 April and id 50 to 20 April..

Answer (score 1):

One method only uses window functions.  You can assign each group of failures a group based on the count of successes up to each row.  Then for each failure group, just take the minimum id for a failure:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 'Failure'
             then min(case when status = 'Failure' then DeliveryId end) over (partition by grp)
        end) as first_failureId
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by DeliveryDate) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32b77df8a74c64709fa0200ae9d32a15) is a db<>fiddle.

Actually, a slightly simpler version assigns the groups in reverse order, so the first record is a failure, not a success, so the `case` in the `min()` is then not necessary:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 'Failure'
             then min(DeliveryId) over (partition by grp)
        end) as first_failureId
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by DeliveryDate desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
order by DeliveryId;
```

Hmmm . . . another approach uses `lag()` to detect when the status changes.  Then use a cumulative max just on the changes:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 'Failure'
             then max(case when prev_status is null or prev_status <> status then DeliveryId end) over (order by DeliveryDate)
        end) as first_failureId
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (order by DeliveryDate) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
order by DeliveryId;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "gaps and islands" question. My favorite article is https://blog.jooq.org/2016/04/25/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/, tip #4.

The key to resolve islands is to use key(ie date) - row_number, and this groups the islands with the same number. The result is similar to yours, but it will work with however many failures without using `lag`. You want to only use the failures here:

```
select *,DeliveryDate-row_number() over (order by DeliveryId asc) as grp
from table1
where Status='Failure'
```

Now that you have this, you can just add dense_rank() over (order by grp) to get the number of failures, maybe also union the successes:

```
;with cte as
(
    select *,DeliveryDate-row_number() over (order by DeliveryId asc) as grp
    from table1
    where Status='Failure'
)
    select 
        cte.*,dense_rank() over (order by grp) as FailureNum
    from cte
union all
    select *,null as grp,null as FailureNum
    from table1
    where Status='Success'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work-in-progress. Need to find a workaround for re-starting count once `Status` changes back to `Success`

Play around with it using https://dbfiddle.uk/

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    DeliveryId int NOT NULL,
    DeliveryDate date NOT NULL,
    Status varchar(max) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO test (DeliveryId,DeliveryDate,Status) 
values 
    (1, '2021-04-14', 'Success'),
    (2, '2021-04-15', 'Failure'),
    (3, '2021-04-16', 'Success'),
    (4, '2021-04-17', 'Success'),
    (5, '2021-04-18', 'Failure'),
    (6, '2021-04-19', 'Failure'),
    (7, '2021-04-20', 'Failure'),
    (8, '2021-04-21', 'Success')

with cte as
(
  SELECT DeliveryId,
         DeliveryDate,
         Status,
         1 as FailedDeliveryId
  FROM test
  WHERE DeliveryId = 1
    UNION all
  SELECT t.DeliveryId,
         t.DeliveryDate,
         t.Status,
         cte.FailedDeliveryId + CASE WHEN cte.Status <> t.Status THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM test as t INNER JOIN cte ON t.DeliveryId - 1 = cte.DeliveryId
)


SELECT 
       DeliveryId,
       DeliveryDate,
       Status,
       FailedDeliveryId
FROM cte       
ORDER BY DeliveryId
```